# Android Google API Keys

Tags: android, google-maps, google-signin, sign, api-key

I'm new to android development and I'm currently working on an app which integrates google maps and google sign in. I read online that I need api keys to activate the apis and I did so. The app worked fine while debugging on my device, but when I published it to the play store, when I try to sign into google nothing happens. People were saying that I need to add credentials and such to the google developers console but I'm not sure how everything comes together. Do I need 2 keys for maps and google sign in? Can anyone explain the whole concept of api keys, release certificates, signing the apk file and what the keystore file is?

Answer (score 0):

For a complete guide about API Key and app's certificate, you may refer to [Maps Android API - Get API Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup).

And to help you in any difficulties and for additional information with using the API, [Google Maps APIs - FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#top_of_page) might come in handy.